# Low level bind of disableProperty and setDisable of a controller

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there a way to do a low level bind but also be able to still do `setDisable(ture/false)` to a controller?

For example:

```
    HBoxSomeBox.disableProperty().bind(new BooleanBinding() { 
        {
            bind(someIntValue);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean computeValue() {
            return someIntValue >=2 ;
        }
    });
```

And somewhere else in the code to do `HBoxSomeBox.setDisable(false)`.

Currently when I try to do that it throws an exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: HBox.disable : A bound value cannot be set.

So is there another way to have a bound controller but also to be able to set it?

Comment: Binding a value means "keep the value the same as this one". Setting a value does not make sense in this context. Could you describe the effect `bind` should have for the property? This seems to be an XY problem to me.

Comment: I want to bind that controller to a certain value that will disable it according to the value, but there can be other reasons to disable that controller. @fabian

Comment: @kuhaku You are contradicting yourself. "Binding" means that `HBoxSomeBox.disableProperty()` *always* has the same value as the value to which you bind it. So if you want to be able to change it "for other reasons", you by definition don't want to bind it. So what do you actually mean?

Comment: Basically to automatically disable it if certain conditions are met, the `someIntValue` is coming from the model and the other reasons are related to the view. I just thought of something, doing this instead: `return someIntValue >=2 || someBoolean;`, `someBoolean` is a data member, and to change that boolean for the other reasons but it doesn't seem to work... @James_D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, you appear to want to disable your control anytime the value of `someIntValue` is at least two, or under other circumstances "dictated by the view". You could either create a `BooleanProperty` representing those other circumstances, and use it in the binding:

```
IntegerProperty someIntProperty = ... ;

BooleanProperty forceDisable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

hboxSomeHBox.disableProperty().bind(new BooleanBinding() {
    {
        bind(someIntValue, forceDisable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean computeValue() {
        return someIntValue.get() >= 2 || forceDisable.get() ;
    }
}
```

or, more succinctly,

```
BooleanProperty forceDisable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

hboxSomeHBox.disableProperty().bind(someIntValue.greaterThanOrEqualTo(2).or(forceDisable));
```

Then calling `forceDisable.set(true);` will disable the control.

You can also achieve this simply with a listener:

```
someIntValue.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue.intValue() >= 2) {
        hboxSomeHBox.setDisable(true);
    }
});
```

Since the disable property is not bound, you are free to set it in the usual way.